# Is there any .gifv or .gif support to be embedded in answers/questions?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I was wondering if there was any support for adding .gifv or .gif files/links in the same format as a regular image would be embedded as so:

[image: Picture]

I think that this could be useful for adding little short clips without a video player. This could be used for instructional purposes or to show how an error is occurring. If this is not a feature, I'd like to request for this to become one. I feel like there is a reason why this hasn't been implemented yet, and if anyone knows why I'd love to know. I always appreciate feedback.

Comment: @MarkKirby Thank you for the link to that post!